# Can't draw border around cells the results to be dumped in an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've created a script to parse the titles and their associated links from a webpage and write the same to an excel file using openpyxl library. The script is doing fine. However, what I can't do is draw border around the cells the results to be written.

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

wb = Workbook()
wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])

def fetch_content(link):
    req = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        title = item.get_text(strip=True)
        post_link = item.get("href")
        yield title,post_link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws = wb.create_sheet("output")
    ws.append(['Title','Link'])
    row = 2
    for title,post_link in fetch_content(link):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value = title
        ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = post_link
        row+=1
    wb.save("SO.xlsx")
```

> How can I draw border around cells the results to be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this want you want?

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

wb = Workbook()
wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])


def fetch_content(link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        yield item.get_text(strip=True), item.get("href")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thin_border = Border(
        left=Side(style='thin'),
        right=Side(style='thin'),
        top=Side(style='thin'),
        bottom=Side(style='thin'),
    )

    ws = wb.create_sheet("output")
    ws.append(['Title', 'Link'])
    row = 2
    for title, post_link in fetch_content(link):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value = title
        ws.cell(row=row, column=1).border = thin_border

        ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = post_link
        ws.cell(row=row, column=2).border = thin_border
        row += 1
    wb.save("SO.xlsx")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did to get the expected output before posing this question. I thought there would be any way not to repeat the line, as in `ws.cell().value` and then again `ws.cell().border`. However, it seems this is the only way. Thanks.